# How to extract numbers from "2x3x4" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working on the [2nd programming puzzle](http://adventofcode.com/day/2) from *Advent of Code*.

I'm given a list of dimensions (*length x width x height*). There are probably over 1000:

```
29x13x26
11x11x14
27x2x5
6x10x13
```

I want to pass the numbers from each line to a method:

```
def calc(l, w, h)
  # performs some calculation
end
```

But I don't know how to extract the numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
a_file = File.open("presents_size.txt", "r")
a_file.each_line("\n") do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: `line.split('x').map(&:to_i) # => [29, 13, 26]` - here you go, these are your numbers

Comment: Don't name your variables and methods in PascalCase. Should be snake_case. `Calc` should be `calc`, `BoxSize` should be `box_size`, etc. In ruby, pascal case naming is for classes/modules.

Comment: Add it as a solution so I can give you credit. Thank you.
EDIT: I'll keep in mind about the naming practices as well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev post it as the answer :)

Comment: What is a "Santa's present"?

Comment: @sawa: just a bit of fluff to make the problem not too boring, I imagine.

Comment: I find it amazing that people find it necessary to edit and downvote my post because of spelling and formatting. Don't get me wrong I am all for proper use of English grammar and spelling but people need to realize that some of us are still in the early stages of learning. My brain is focused on math, logic and wrapping my mind around concepts that I've never thought of before. I am sorry for not paying enough attention to those things but I am a firm believer that your time could spent in a better way.

Comment: @thermobeelearns: someone fixed your spelling/grammar. The question now reads better (good for the site). What are you complaining about, again? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I appreciate the help more than I can describe in English.  It was more a general comment than anything else. Like I said I just feel like the precious time of that person could be used in a more productive manner.

Comment: @thermobeelearns there's no need to hurry, neither in writing a question, nor in selecting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
line.split('x').map(&:to_i) # => [29, 13, 26]
```

here you go, these are your numbers (which you can multiply or whatever).

Comment: further if you want to pass this `output` to the `calc` method, you can do this by using `calc(*output)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`scanf`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/scanf/rdoc/Scanf.html) library:

```
require 'scanf'

'29x13x26'.scanf('%dx%dx%d') #=> [29, 13, 26]
```

`%d` matches an integer and `x` matches a literal "x".

To scan a whole file, `scanf` can be used in block mode:

```
require 'scanf'

File.open('words.txt', 'rb') do |f|
  f.scanf('%dx%dx%d') do |l, w, h|
    # do something with l, w, h
    p l: l, w: w, h: h
  end
end
```

Output:

```
{:l=>29, :w=>13, :h=>26}
{:l=>11, :w=>11, :h=>14}
{:l=>27, :w=>2, :h=>5}
{:l=>6, :w=>10, :h=>13}
```

Comment: This is actually what I had in mind when I was thinking about it last night. I just couldn't figure it out on my own. I made the program work with @sergio's method but I definitely learned something. Thank you Stefan.